# What are consonants without secondary articulation called?

Tags: terminology

How can we concisely describe a consonant that is non-velarized, non-palatalized, non-glottalized, ....?

Is there an adjective for "no secondary articulation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common word I've heard is "plain"—for example, the reconstructed phonemes **ḱ*, **kʷ*, and **k* in Proto-Indo-European can be called "palatovelar", "labiovelar", and "plain velar". But this is mainly used when it's important to make the distinction clear; often, just "velar" on its own is enough.

The Latin word "tenuis" (literally "thin") is sometimes used as a synonym for "plain" or "not otherwise marked" in phonology, but I would put a caveat on that one. It's generally used for manner of articulation, not place, so people will generally associate "tenuis velar stop" with "`/k/` as opposed to `/g/` or `/kʰ/`", not "`/k/` as opposed to `/kˤ/` or `/kʷ/`". But for certain types of secondary articulation (palatalization in Russian, perhaps) it might be a fitting term.

Answer (score 0):

In Russian we talk about *hard* and *soft* consonants, as non-palatalized and palatalized respectively. These are not universal scientific terms, of course, but rather established ones in the context of this language.

Comment: But neither is without secondary articulation – the opposition is between palatalized and velarized.